# Bootstrap Navbar length mismatch with body content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mkdocs

I am using mkdocs default bootstrap theme (Bootswatch v4.1.3) to create a website that supports markdown.

In the body I have created a large width table and due to that, navbar appears shorter than body, when we scroll to rightmost. Adding image snap.

I tried increasing the length of navbar using "width" attribute of class navbar. But that breaks the alignment of text "Test Site" with below box as shown in image.

```
.navbar {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#54b4eb,#2fa4e7 60%,#1d9ce5);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#54b4eb,#2fa4e7 60%,#1d9ce5);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #178acc;
    filter: `enter code here`progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff54b4eb',endColorstr='#ff1d9ce5',GradientType=0);
    filter: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Adding theme html base template of mkdocs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      {%- block site_meta %}
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        {% if page and page.is_homepage %}<meta name="description" content="{{ config['site_description'] }}">{% endif %}
        {% if config.site_author %}<meta name="author" content="{{ config.site_author }}">{% endif %}
        {% if page and page.canonical_url %}<link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.canonical_url }}">{% endif %}
        {% if config.site_favicon %}<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ config.site_favicon|url }}">
        {% else %}<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ 'img/favicon.ico'|url }}">{% endif %}
      {%- endblock %}

      {%- block htmltitle %}
        <title>{% if page and page.title and not page.is_homepage %}{{ page.title }} - {% endif %}{{ config.site_name }}</title>
      {%- endblock %}

      {%- block styles %}
        <link href="{{ 'css/bootstrap.min.css'|url }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ 'css/font-awesome.min.css'|url }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ 'css/base.css'|url }}" rel="stylesheet">
        {%- if config.theme.highlightjs %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/{{ config.theme.hljs_style }}.min.css">
        {%- endif %}
        {%- for path in config['extra_css'] %}
        <link href="{{ path|url }}" rel="stylesheet">
        {%- endfor %}
      {%- endblock %}

      {%- block libs %}

        <script src="{{ 'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'|url }}" defer></script>
        <script src="{{ 'js/bootstrap.min.js'|url }}" defer></script>
        {%- if config.theme.highlightjs %}
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
        {%- for lang in config.theme.hljs_languages %}
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/languages/{{lang}}.min.js"></script>
        {%- endfor %}
        <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
        {%- endif %}
      {%- endblock %}

      {%- block analytics %}
        {%- if config.google_analytics %}
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', '{{ config.google_analytics[0] }}', '{{ config.google_analytics[1] }}');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        {%- endif %}
      {%- endblock %}

      {%- block extrahead %} {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body{% if page and page.is_homepage %} class="homepage"{% endif %}>
        <div class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-{% if config.theme.nav_style == "light" %}light{% else %}dark{% endif %} bg-{{ config.theme.nav_style }}">
            <div class="container">

                {%- block site_name %}
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ nav.homepage.url|url }}">{{ config.site_name }}</a>
                {%- endblock %}

                {%- if nav|length>1 or (page and (page.next_page or page.previous_page)) or config.repo_url %}
                <!-- Expander button -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                {%- endif %}

                <!-- Expanded navigation -->
                <div id="navbar-collapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  {%- block site_nav %}
                    {%- if nav|length>1 %}
                        <!-- Main navigation -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        {%- for nav_item in nav %}
                        {%- if nav_item.children %}
                            <li class="dropdown{% if nav_item.active %} active{% endif %}">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ nav_item.title }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                {%- for nav_item in nav_item.children %}
                                    {% include "nav-sub.html" %}
                                {%- endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        {%- else %}
                            <li class="navitem{% if nav_item.active %} active{% endif %}">
                                <a href="{{ nav_item.url|url }}" class="nav-link">{{ nav_item.title }}</a>
                            </li>
                        {%- endif %}
                        {%- endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {%- endif %}
                  {%- endblock %}

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                      {%- block search_button %}
                        {%- if 'search' in config['plugins'] %}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mkdocs_search_modal">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {%- endif %}
                      {%- endblock %}

                      {%- block next_prev %}
                        {%- if page and (page.next_page or page.previous_page) %}
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a rel="prev" {% if page.previous_page %}href="{{ page.previous_page.url|url }}" class="nav-link"{% else %}class="nav-link disabled"{% endif %}>
                                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a rel="next" {% if page.next_page %}href="{{ page.next_page.url|url }}" class="nav-link"{% else %}class="nav-link disabled"{% endif %}>
                                    Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {%- endif %}
                      {%- endblock %}

                      {%- block repo %}
                        {%- if page and page.edit_url %}
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="{{ page.edit_url }}" class="nav-link">
                                    {%- if config.repo_name == 'GitHub' -%}
                                        <i class="fa fa-github"></i> Edit on {{ config.repo_name }}
                                    {%- elif config.repo_name == 'Bitbucket' -%}
                                        <i class="fa fa-bitbucket"></i> Edit on {{ config.repo_name }}
                                    {%- elif config.repo_name == 'GitLab' -%}
                                        <i class="fa fa-gitlab"></i> Edit on {{ config.repo_name }}
                                    {%- else -%}
                                    Edit on {{ config.repo_name }}
                                    {%- endif -%}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {%- elif config.repo_url %}
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="{{ config.repo_url }}" class="nav-link">
                                    {%- if config.repo_name == 'GitHub' -%}
                                        <i class="fa fa-github"></i> {{ config.repo_name }}
                                    {%- elif config.repo_name == 'Bitbucket' -%}
                                        <i class="fa fa-bitbucket"></i> {{ config.repo_name }}
                                    {%- elif config.repo_name == 'GitLab' -%}
                                        <i class="fa fa-gitlab"></i> {{ config.repo_name }}
                                    {%- else -%}
                                    {{ config.repo_name }}
                                    {%- endif -%}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {%- endif %}
                      {%- endblock %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                {%- block content %}
                    <div class="col-md-3">{% include "toc.html" %}</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9" role="main">{% include "content.html" %}</div>
                {%- endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="col-md-12">
          {%- block footer %}
            <hr>
            {%- if config.copyright %}
                <p>{{ config.copyright }}</p>
            {%- endif %}

          {%- endblock %}
        </footer>

      {%- block scripts %}
        <script>
            var base_url = {{ base_url | tojson }},
                shortcuts = {{ config.theme.shortcuts | tojson }};
        </script>
        <script src="{{ 'js/base.js'|url }}" defer></script>
        {%- for path in config['extra_javascript'] %}
        <script src="{{ path|url }}" defer></script>
        {%- endfor %}
      {%- endblock %}

        {% if 'search' in config['plugins'] %}{%- include "search-modal.html" %}{% endif %}
        {%- include "keyboard-modal.html" %}

    </body>
</html>
{% if page and page.is_homepage %}
<!--
MkDocs version : {{ mkdocs_version }}
Build Date UTC : {{ build_date_utc }}
-->
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is the navbar in a container? It might be in a container that is not full width.

Comment: navbar is not in container. I have added the theme html file of mkdocs in question